# Program to conjugate

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that will conjugate a verb in multiple forms.

So I write a function that will allow me to get the part that is kepted and conjugate it. Fixed rule : whole word except last 2 chars.

I am used to OO, and I can't seem to make it work, while it seems a basic program.

I obtain something with weird : here is a screen at the end of the execution, that will be more explicit

[image]

I think I missed a little something in my course (probably in the char[] part...), that has a huge impact, but I can't seem to find it.
I am opened to all observations on my code, since I am beginning, and I prefer going on a solid basis right now, better that later.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void RacineVerbe(char verbeEntier[], char dest[]);
int myStrLen(char *s);
int main()
{
    char *string;
    char *racine;
    string = (char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    racine = (char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    printf("Quel verbe?\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    RacineVerbe(string, racine);
    printf("%s", racine);
    printf("%sASSE\n", racine);
    printf("%sASSES\n", racine);
    printf("%sAT\n", racine);
    printf("%sASSIONS\n", racine);
    printf("%sASSIEZ\n", racine);
    printf("%sASSENT\n", racine);
    return 0;
}

void RacineVerbe(char verbeEntier[], char dest[]){
int i;
int l = myStrLen(verbeEntier);
for( i = 0; i < l -2 ; i++){
    dest[i] = verbeEntier[i];
}
dest[i+1] = "\0";
}

int myStrLen(char *s){
    int i = 0;
    while(*s++)i++;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `dest[i+1] = "\0";` -> `dest[i] = '\0';` You should get a warning for that.

Comment: you should remove the (char*) cast from malloc when using C

Comment: "*I am used to OO*" -- and of course, you could do this using an OO design in C as well, e.g. you could separate your generic strategy from some language-specific implementation ...

Comment: Please do not show text as pictures. This is no artwork. Please c&p your text into your question.

Comment: @Gerhardh well sorry, but I wasn't able to copy/paste the error message as it was, so I had to do that.

Comment: There is no error message in your question. Just text output (with some garbage text in between)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in you `RacineVerbe` because you assigned *string literal* to single character (not a poitner to characters).

In that situation, *string literal* returns you the address where it is in memory and you assigned to `dest[i+i]` *LSB* byte of that address and it may be or may not be visible character. I can assure, your compiler gave you at least warning for that.

Second problem is where you did assignment. You should do it to `dest[i]` as `i` was last time incremented in `for` loop before check failed and therefore `i` already points to place where `0` should be written.

```
void RacineVerbe(char verbeEntier[], char dest[]){
    int i;
    int l = myStrLen(verbeEntier);
    for( i = 0; i < l -2 ; i++){
        dest[i] = verbeEntier[i];
    }
    dest[i] = 0; //This line was rewritten.
}
```

And as already mentioned, try to *NOT* cast return result of `malloc`.

Comment: Indeed, taht whas this. Why does a 0 works to. Shouldn't it be like ClsForCookies said '0'? Both answsers are still valid.

Comment: `0` and `'\0'` are the same and both represent `0x00` (or false) while `'0'` represents ASCII character `48`.

Answer (score 2):

You invoked UB when you wrote `dest[i+1] = "\0";` since `dest[i+1]` expects a `char` and you assigned `"\0"` into it, which is a string literal. Replace it with `'\0'`

Note that `string = (char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));` ---> `string = malloc(200);` since casting is not needed in `malloc` in C, and considered bad ([as you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)) and also `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, 1

Comment: To be really safe for bugs, this should be used: `string = malloc(sizeof(*string) * 200);` Using dereference syntax inside `sizeof`.

Comment: This is indeed a useless cast on malloc. But useless doesn't make it failed. It was the +1 tough. Thanks.

Comment: @Zaphod I didn't mean to say the cast caused problems. I just said you could and should remove it. Not that it will make any visible changes in execution